# Understanding the context of *this* inside classes

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following code.

```
class Node {
     constructor(value, parent, possibleChildren = []) {
     this.value = value;
     this.parent = parent;
     this.children = []
     this.setChildren(possibleChildren);
   }

setChildren(possibleChildren) {
  if (possibleChildren.length === 0) return [];

  while (possibleChildren.length > 0) {
      const value = possibleChildren.pop();
      // keyword *this* messes up the context. Save them function calls for lazy execution
      let childNode = () => new Node(value, this, possibleChildren);
      this.children.push(childNode);
    }
    this.children = this.children.map(child => child())
  }

getChildrenValues() {
    return this.children.map((child) => child.value);
  }
}
```

In the above the `this.children` variable is set properly. If I save the `this.children` array directly, without wrapping it in a function, I see incorrect children being set.

Example:

```
setChildren(possibleChildren) {
  if (possibleChildren.length === 0) return [];

  while (possibleChildren.length > 0) {
    const value = possibleChildren.pop();
    // keyword *this* messes up the context. Save them function calls for lazy execution
    let childNode = new Node(value, this, possibleChildren);
    this.children.push(childNode);
  }
}
```

I know that the context of *this* is not consitent without the function wrapper. What I do not understand is why. Any ideas?

Calling `getChildrenValues` on the first example returns ["A", "B", "C"].

Calling `getChildrenValues` on the second example returns ["C"]

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value, parent, possibleChildren = []) {
    this.value = value;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = []
    this.setChildren(possibleChildren);
  }

  setChildren(possibleChildren) {
    if (possibleChildren.length === 0) return [];

    while (possibleChildren.length > 0) {
      const value = possibleChildren.pop();
      // keyword *this* messes up the context. Save them function calls for lazy execution
      const childNode = new Node(value, this, possibleChildren);
      this.children.push(childNode);
    }
  }
  
  getChildrenValues() {
    return this.children.map((child) => child.value);
  }
}

let root = new Node(null, null, "ABC".split(""));
console.log(root.getChildrenValues())
```

Comment: This has been _extensively_ explained elsewhere. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This doesn't look like the usual problem with `this` in callbacks. The second version doesn't have a callback.

Comment: Both pieces of code should have one and the same reference to `this`. I don't see why it would be different.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: How do you even determine that the value of `this` is lost? If you have a breakpoint, you'd observe it's *different* but that is going to be because of the recursion. If you do the instantiation inside the loop, then that will kick off another `setChildren` by the new Node being created. This the `this` would be that new node. However, the whole context would also be different anyway and unrelated to the parent executing `setChildren`. Is *that* what you're seeing and miscategorising it as an error? As @Barmar an example can clear things up.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `this` in the example? It seems to work exactly as it should. The only thing that might be wrong is that you're passing around the same array of `possibleChildren`, so modifications to it in recursive calls will also change what the array is for the parent. While if you delay the instantiation of the children, the array would be processed and empty before they are initialised, so they'd have no possible children themselves. But that's not really related to `this` at all. I don't see why `possibleChidren` should even be passed down.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the context of `this` is not consistent without the function wrapper. What I do not understand is why?

This has nothing to do with the `this` keyword. Since you used an arrow function, it does refer to exactly the same object in both your code snippets, there is no difference.

The reason why you get different results from the two snippets is the lazy execution, but not with respect to `this`, but rather the `possibleChildren` array. In your first code, the `while (possibleChildren.length > 0)` runs and empties the `possibleChildren` array **before** you do the recursive `new Node` calls. In the second example, you call `new Node` **during** that loop, and you pass on the reference to the *same* `possibleChildren` array, which is being emptied by the recursive call and the loop therefore terminates right after the first iteration.

To fix this, just don't recursively pass the `possibleChildren`:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value, parent, childrenValues = []) {
    this.value = value;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = []
    this.setChildrenValues(childrenValues);
  }

  setChildrenValues(childrenValues) {
    for (let i=childrenValues.length; i--; ) {
      const value = childrenValues[i];
      const childNode = new Node(value, this  );
//                                           ^ no third argument, no grandchildren
      this.children.push(childNode);
    }
  }
  
  getChildrenValues() {
    return this.children.map((child) => child.value);
  }
}

let root = new Node(null, null, "ABC".split(""));
console.log(root.getChildrenValues())
```